# How do i cache api in reactjs Progressive Web App(Pwa) to add Offline support?

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps

I have registered my service worker by adding serviceWorker.register(); in my code.In create-react-app Api results are not cached.How do we cache Api result so we counld improve Offline support.

Comment: Do you use redux or mobx or apollo or something else to manage your app state?

Comment: I use Redux for state management.

Comment: Check [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)

Answer (score 1):

you can cache the network responses and can be served from it as below

```js
window.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.open('your-app').then(function(cache) {
      return cache.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
        return response || fetch(event.request).then(function(response) {
          cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
          return response;
        });
      });
    })
  );
});
```

[resource](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker)

Comment: Just a note, that is a very simple, minimal example. For a real production application you will need to have a much more sophisticated solution to manage what strategy is used for different resources, data, which includes how cached assets are invalidated etc.